# App Center was started without app secret, but the service requires it; not starting service Crashes

Tags: c#, maui, visual-studio-app-center

I am getting this error in a Maui app when I try to start App Center:

*"App Center was started without app secret, but the service requires it; not starting service Crashes."*

Here is the code I am using:

```
            AppCenter.Configure(appCenterSecret);
            if (AppCenter.Configured)
            {
                AppCenter.Start(typeof(Crashes));
                AppCenter.Start(typeof(Analytics));
            }
```

What is even stranger is that if I use the following code it seems to work ok (but I don't get Analytics):

```
            AppCenter.Start(appCenterSecret, typeof(Crashes));
```

Has anyone seen this before?
Thanks

Comment: It's strange that the above code doesn't work. Does it work when you combine that last method like this:

`AppCenter.Start(appCenterSecret, typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));`

Comment: Hi @GeraldVersluis yes that worked! Pretty sure I had tried that combination in the past without success but working now. Post this as an answer and I will tick it off. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's strange that the above code doesn't work, that method should also work according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin#421-maui-and-xamarinforms).

Another way to also initialize is like this:

`AppCenter.Start(appCenterSecret, typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));`